# ab benchmark put test fails with nginx

Tags: nginx, put

Following is my nginx.conf

```
root   html;
index  index.html index.htm;
client_body_temp_path  client_tmp;
dav_methods  PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;
create_full_put_path   on;
dav_access             group:rw  all:rw;
client_max_body_size 10000m;
```

While ab put test is run , following error is observed -

## ab -v 2 -n 1 -c 1 -u testfile https://102.1.1.77/

```
Start Time: 1594207246
Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
Extended master secret: yes
LOG: header received:
HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict
Server: nginx/1.18.0
Date: Wed, 08 Jul 2020 11:20:46 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 151
Connection: close

<html>
<head><title>409 Conflict</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>409 Conflict</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.18.0</center>
</body>
</html>

WARNING: Response code not 2xx (409)
..done
```